# Can I limit what my friends can see of my Likes and Comments on the FB News Ticker?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I have set strict privacy settings on Facebook to "only me" on my Timeline, Friends List and page "Likes". Yet a friend of mine told me the other day they saw a number of my likes and comments appearing on their News Ticker.

I'd like the privacy of not having others seeing them. Checking similar questions it appears my only recourse is to check whether the person whose comments I want to "Like" or comment is set to public; and if that is the case, the advice is since nothing can be done I should just not post comments on those pages because they may become public knowledge to all my friends.

Does it help if I comment directly on my friends' pages rather on my Timeline..or is this just going to appear on News Tickers no matter where I act? I hate to think I can no longer offer support to friends via comments or likes for fear that the whole world will see them.

Answer (score 2):

The visibility of your comments and likes is dictated by the person/page you are liking or commenting on. If you comment on a friend’s post that is visible to `Friends`, then all their friends will be able to read that comment. Furthermore, your comment may appear (based on Facebook’s relevance algorithm) in the news feeds of those friends you have in common.

This extends to any kind of visibility assigned to the post that you like/comment on. So if they have set visibility to `Friends of Friends` then your like/comment will be visible to their friends’ friends; once again if that group encompasses your own friends, then your action may appear in their news feeds.